# Django annotate with values: how to access values?

Tags: django

I have a model with "disposals" and a model with "salesman".
I want to get the average discount of everye salesman.
Here's what I'm trying:

```
sm = Disposal.objects.annotate(average_discount=Avg('discount')).values('average_discount','sm__fname','sm__lname').order_by('-discount')
    for s in sm:
         data[0] = data[0]+s.sm__fname+','+s.sm__lname+','+str(s.average_discount)
```

Now I get this error:

> Disposal object has no attribute
>   sm__fname

The query runs fine when I execute it in the django shell - but how can I access the values?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields) says, using `values` gives you a list of **dictionaries**, not model objects. So each `s` doesn't have an attribute `sm_whatever`, it has a dictionary key. So try this:

```
s['sm__lname']
```

However, I must say that I don't see the need to use `values` here at all. You would be better off just getting the actual objects:

```
sm = Disposal.objects.annotate(average_discount=Avg('discount')).order_by('-discount')
```

and then accessing the relevant related objects normally: `s.fname`.